# Static IP address problem

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

I am trying to set static IP address on my Pi following a tutorial from instructables - [How To Assign A Static IP to The Raspberry Pi](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Assign-A-Static-IP-to-The-Raspberry-Pi/step3/Execution/), but the problem is in the tutorial it says to find DHCP heading. In my case there is no DHCP heading.

[image: No DHCP heading]

What can be done in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line in question, but yours currently says `manual` instead of `dhcp`.  Change it from `manual` to `static`.